# Creating streams instead of temporary files and use them and discard them

Tags: java, servlets, stream

I want to write to a stream and use it immediately, rather than writing it to file and reading.  FIles will not be thread safe and I think it will possibly affect performance.

```
    //set property to an existing file
    prop.setProperty("$quoteValidity",""no");
    prop.setProperty("$date", "today");
    prop.setProperty("$quantitySum",  Integer.toString(quantitySum));

    //store it in temporary location
    prop.store(new FileOutputStream("<Temp file location>"), null);

    //open that temp file as stream
    InputStream propfile = new FileInputStream("<Temp file location>");

    List<Order> orderList = XmlToList.makeOrderFromNodeList(orderNode);
    //use that temp file
    Testground.generateXlsx(propfile,orderList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use a ByteArrayOutputStream instead of a FileOuputStream.  You can then call

```
 byte[] bytes=byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
```

on the ByteArrayOutputStream to get the bytes

Then construct a ByteArrayInputStream(bytes) and pass that into Testground

Comment: can you please elaborate i have been searching regarding your answer and could not relate, please give an example in relation to this particular scenario and i will replicate it across my project

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html documents the class.   There are dozens of examples on the intertoobz if you use Google to look for "ByteArrayOutputStream howto"